# How do I make biblatex to put a period after a closing parentheses?

Tags: biblatex

My MWE looks like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Oberländer-Târnoveanu1978,
   author       = {Oberländer-Târnoveanu, Ernest},
   title        = {Aspecte ale circulaţiei monedei greceşti în Dobrogea de Nord (sec. VI î.e.n.--I e.n.)},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1978},
   pages        = {59--87},
   volume       = {XI},
}

@article{Ocheşeanu1970,
   author       = {Ocheşeanu, Radu},
   title        = {Monedele basileului Moskon aflate în colecţiile Muzeului de arheologie Constanţa},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1970},
   pages        = {125--129},
   volume       = {III},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am aware that the difference is the closing parentheses `)`. But how can I nevertheless get a period after the title which has the parentheses?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex`'s punctuation tracker basically ignores any kinds of brackets and parentheses, so for punctuation purposes the title

```
title = {Aspecte ale circulaţiei monedei greceşti în Dobrogea de Nord (sec. VI î.e.n.--I e.n.)},
```

is the same as

```
 title = {Aspecte ale circulaţiei monedei greceşti în Dobrogea de Nord sec. VI î.e.n.--I e.n.},
```

Since that title ends with a dot, `biblatex` suppresses the following period to avoid double punctuation.

You can tell `biblatex` not to ignore brackets in punctuation tracking. ([The original definition of `\blx@setsfcodes` in `biblatex.sty`, ll. 1705-1720 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L1705-L1720) sets the `\sfcodes` of brackets to 0, we set it to 1000.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@setsfcodes{%
  \let\blx@setsfcodes\relax
  \let\frenchspacing\blx@setfrcodes
  \let\nonfrenchspacing\blx@setencodes
  \ifnum\sfcode`\.>2000
    \blx@setencodes
  \else
    \blx@setfrcodes
  \fi
  \@setquotesfcodes
  \sfcode`\(=\@m
  \sfcode`\)=\@m
  \sfcode`\[=\@m
  \sfcode`\]=\@m
  \sfcode`\<=\@m
  \sfcode`\>=\@m}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Oberländer-Târnoveanu1978,
   author       = {Oberländer-Târnoveanu, Ernest},
   title        = {Aspecte ale circulaţiei monedei greceşti
                   în Dobrogea de Nord (sec. VI î.e.n.--I e.n.)},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1978},
   pages        = {59--87},
   volume       = {XI},
}
@article{Ocheşeanu1970,
   author       = {Ocheşeanu, Radu},
   title        = {Monedele basileului Moskon aflate
                   în colecţiile Muzeului de arheologie Constanţa},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1970},
   pages        = {125--129},
   volume       = {III},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ernest Oberländer-Târnoveanu. “Aspecte ale circulat ¸iei monedei grece¸ stiˆın Dobrogea de Nord (sec. VI ˆı.e.n.–I e.n.)”. In: Pontica XI (1978), pp. 59–87.]

---

In case you'd rather preserve normal `biblatex` behaviour, you can add `\@` to the end of this title to tell the punctuation tracker to ignore the dot in the brackets.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Oberländer-Târnoveanu1978,
   author       = {Oberländer-Târnoveanu, Ernest},
   title        = {Aspecte ale circulaţiei monedei greceşti
                   în Dobrogea de Nord (sec. VI î.e.n.--I e.n.)\@},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1978},
   pages        = {59--87},
   volume       = {XI},
}
@article{Ocheşeanu1970,
   author       = {Ocheşeanu, Radu},
   title        = {Monedele basileului Moskon aflate
                   în colecţiile Muzeului de arheologie Constanţa},
   journaltitle = {Pontica},
   date         = {1970},
   pages        = {125--129},
   volume       = {III},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is the same in the MWE.